# i want to use iconv function for array?

Tags: php, arrays, iconv

this is my array:

```
$array = array(
                'name' => $burcname . ' Günlük yorumum',
                'link' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/gunlukburcpaylas/sonuc.php?burc='. $burc,
                'description' => $burcname . ' Günlük yorumu. Sizde her gün profilinizde günlük burç yorumunuz için uygulamaya katılın..',
                'message' => $aciklama,
                'picture' => $picture
                );
```

iconv as: `$example = iconv('UTF-8','ISO-8859-9',$array);`

But this is array. and dont work. What can i do?

Comment: foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
   {
    $array[$key] = iconv('ISO-8859-9', 'UTF-8', $value);
   }

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to iterate the array contents, or use a function like `array_walk`.

**Foreach loop (untested)**

```
foreach(array_keys($array) as $key){
    $array[$key] = iconv('UTF-8','ISO-8859-9', $array[$key]);
}
```

The reason you need to use `array_keys` in this example is because a standard `foreach` loop with `foreach($array as $key => $value)` or `foreach($array as $value)` modifications made to `$value` are not preserved.

**Using `array_walk` (untested)**

```
function convert(&$value, $key){
    $value = iconv('UTF-8','ISO-8859-9', $value);
}
array_walk($array, 'convert');
```

If you are using PHP > 5.3 then you can use a lambda function instead.

Answer (score 5):

array_walk_deep function (tested)

```
$array = array("a",
    array("b",
      array("c",
        "d"
      )
    )
);

function array_walk_deep(&$items,$func){
    foreach ($items as &$item) {
        if(is_array($item))
          array_walk_deep($item,$func);
        else
          $item = $func($item);
    }
}

array_walk_deep($array, 'strtoupper');

print_r($array);
```

Comment: PHP has an built-in function [array_walk_recursive()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) now.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to return the results from the foreach by reference instead of by value:

```
foreach( $array as &$value ) {
  $value = iconv( 'UTF-8','ISO-8859-9', $value );
}
```

The '**&**' in front of the value variable lets you use the actual array value instead of a copy.  :)